# Как обойти кеширование User Agent?

Tags: php

Не думал что такое возможно, но столкнулся с такой чехардой:

У меня в темплейте (PHP) описана функция, которая по 2 параметрам (по установкам сервера, по сигнатуре User Agent) проверят девайс, мне это необходимо для разной структуры вывода материала, для стационарников сложная стуктура и куча всякого js, для мобильных все попроще.

Так вот столкнулся с тем, что при включенном кешировании, user agent на разных устройствах выдает значения первого захода, то есть зашел с компа, user agent компа будет и на девайсах (инет wi-fi), как такое возможно? Он кешируется(это же бред)? Как обойти кеширование user agent?

Comment: О каком кешировании идет речь?

Comment: кеширование cms

Comment: Попробуйте минимальный код представить, расскажите какой сервер и программы. Может гуру подскажут.

Comment: Скрипт у вас не должен кешироваться, который контент формирует в зависимости от юзерагента.

Comment: точно!!! вот откуда ноги растут, спасибо, вам светлая голова.